# Remove __metadata tag from an odata response

Tags: odata

I'd like to remove the __metadata tag from responses in my odata queries.  I know you can use $select to specify what fields you want, but I can't seem to get rid of __metadata.  This would compact my queries by about 50 to 75%.

Any ideas on how you can remove the __metadata tag?

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed in this question: [WCF Data Services: How to avoid the __metadata members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492706/wcf-data-services-how-to-avoid-the-metadata-members/3494854#3494854)
In short the WCF Data Services product doesn't support this currently. The main reason is, that the returned data is not OData compliant anymore as well as it might make it impossible for clients to perform certain types of operations.