# Removing __metadata from WCF data service

Tags: json, metadata, wcf-data-services

My question is similar to [WCF Data Services: How to avoid the __metadata members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492706/wcf-data-services-how-to-avoid-the-metadata-members).

I wanted to map the following Json to model class.

```
{
"d" : [
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://172.xx.x.xxx:81/NotificationDataService.svc/Notifications(1)", "type":      "MyModel.Notification"
}, "Id": 1, "Message": "This is a test notification"
}
]
}
```

But with this __metadata member i'm stuck at the moment. Is there anyway i can remove this? Or Can anybody help me how to map this json to a model class?

Tx.

Comment: If you're able to use the new v3 OData JSON format, that would be easier to work with. In that format, if you want just the raw data and no metadata, you can request "application/json;odata=nometadata" in the Accept header. This is only a solution if the server you're talking to supports v3 JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove _metadata tag. It generally comes with it.